# Treating a variable as vector

Tags: r, vectorization

```
v=c(96,94,101,84,99,106,85,98,98,85,95,108,84,98,114,86,97,109,84,95,105,83,97,
  100,81,93,102)

rep1=array(v,dim=c(3,3,3))

u=c(84,95,105,85,97,104,86,90,103,80,93,110,82,99,102,84,95,100,83,92,102,80,96,
  111,79,93,108)

rep2=array(u,dim=c(3,3,3))

rep=rep1+rep2

f=function(x1,x2,x3){
   l=x1
  return(l)
```

}

```
 for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
     for(k in 1:3){
     if(f(i,j,k)%%3==1)L=rep[i,j,k]
     }
  }
}
```

here L is taking the last value for which the condition is satisfied . But i want that L will be a vector which will take all the values that will satisfy the condition.

Comment: Please show the expected output of your example.

Comment: @Roland that is, L will take those values where "rep" array has index 1 in row, ie L=c(180,169,171,165,166,170,167,163,160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on your loop:

```
L <- c()
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
    for(k in 1:3){
      if(f(i,j,k)%%3==1) L <- c(L, rep[i,j,k])
    }
  }
}
# [1] 180 165 167 169 166 163 171 170 160
```

Here is another more esoteric one:

```
as.vector( t( rep[ (1:3) %% 3 == 1,,] ) )
# [1] 180 165 167 169 166 163 171 170 160
```

Comment: Why do you make it so complicated? `as.vector(t(rep[1,,]))` is the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Roland: I assumed that the condition in the `if` statement was here for a reason, maybe for the code to work on a larger dimension data set.

Comment: yes , you are right @VincentGuillemot. I need the condition for confounding treatment combination in factorial design.